# HDL counter and flag coding style

Tags: verilog, hdl, digital-logic

In Verilog/VHDL, lets say I have a 4 bit counter, and a flag that should be asserted when the counter equals between 4 and 8. There are two ways to implement this

```
    if((cntr>=4)&&(cntr<8))
        flag <=1;
     else
       flag <= 0;
```

Or, I could do this

```
   if(cntr==4)
       flag<=1;
    else if (cntr==8)
       flag<=0;
```

It seems to me that functionally, these do the same thing.

Is there any reason one would be better than the other? style-wise?  How about for synthesis/implementation?

Comment: Is there a typo in your question? In the second code block's `else if` statement you are resetting the `cntr`?

Comment: correct. I will fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both examples, `flag` will be synthesised as a flip-flop. This is because (I assume) you are driving it from within a clocked always block, ie your two examples are:

```
always @(posedge clk)
  if ((cntr>=4)&&(cntr<8))
    flag <= 1;
  else
    flag <= 0;
```

and

```
always @(posedge clk)
  if (cntr==4)
    flag <= 1;
  else if (cntr==8)
    flag <= 0;
```

Both examples are simple (2-state) FSMs. There is little to choose between them. Both will be implemented by a flip-flop (`flag`) whose D-input is driven by a small amount of combinational logic. The only difference is that that combinational logic may be smaller with the second example than the first because implementing `==` generally requires less area than implementing `<` or `>`.